# Function to fetch Entities only works when called from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, function, core-data

I wrote a function that is supposed to fetch all Objects from a certain Entity and then put all kinds of one attribute into an array. Strangely my function only returns values when called from the AppDelegate? Whenever I try to call it from somewhere else it just returns an empty array

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

func fetchAllFractions() -> [String] {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate!.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Deputies")

    var fractions: [String] = []
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Deputies] //Deputies is the Entity
        print(results.count)
        for deputy in results {
            //check if the Array of fractions already containts the deputies fraction
            if fractions.contains(deputy.fraction!) {
            } else {
                //if not, add it to the array
                fractions.append(deputy.fraction!)
            }
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Error Fetching Fractions", error)
    }
    print(fractions)
    //return array of fractions
    return fractions
}
```

Comment: @Joakim Danielson It returns only an empty array. I call the function with. Let fractions = fetchAllFractions()

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Where should that typo be? The functions works from the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. From there I get "["FDP", "SPD", "DIE LINKE", "AfD", "CDU/CSU", "fraktionslos", "DIE GRÜNEN"]" In the console (Thats all the fractions). When calling the function from my Table View Controller I get "[]"

Comment: Oh yes I copied it wrong. Thanks :D